# composerでpackagistのライブラリをインストールする時の確認方法

Tags: php, composer

composerのデフォルトであるpackagistは製作者以外でもライブラリが登録出来るようですが
packagistで見つけたライブラリの出元の確かさを確認するにはどのような方法があるのでしょうか

個人的にはライブラリのサイトからpackagistへのリンクの有無くらいしか判別方法を持っていません。
せめてcomposerが取りに行くURLが事前に分かればマシなのですが。。

Comment: packagist.org上でパッケージ詳細（https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel とか）を見ると、ページ右側にリポジトリのURLが書いてありますが、composerコマンドでそれを知る方法がないか、ということでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えて頂いたURLを見るのがpackagist側から出来る最善の確認方法のようですね。ただやはり公式サイトからpackagistへのリンクを貼っているケース以外はpackagistのライブラリの正当性が保証されないのはどうしようもないのでしょうね。